# Oracle trigger which invokes another trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Bit of a tricky scenario.

Before Insert Trigger on Child_Table:

- sets the value of Child_Table.Field1 to "A"
- Issues update command on Parent_Table

Before Update Trigger on Parent_Table:

- Sets :new.Field1 = Child_Table.Field1

Short question - Will Parent_Table.Field1 = "A"?

Long question -
Will the Child_Table trigger have already completed and committed the value of "A" to Child_Table.Field1 so that it's available to Parent_Table?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes.

Longer answer - An `update` issued by a trigger is a just like any other update, and will trigger a a subsequent `on update` trigger. Note that the unless you do so *explicitly*, a statement in a trigger does not commit.   However, since it runs in **the same transaction** as the following trigger, any changes it will make will be available to the following trigger.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this very much!

Comment: But how do you get the value of "Child_Table.Field1" while inside the Trigger on Parent_Table ?? I just did a test, and although I may be missing something, I just get an `no data found` when the trigger on the parent tries to access the new row in Child (which doesn't yet exist - ie BEFORE update ... )

Comment: Oh wait ... it's a red herring.  You don't need a BEFORE UPDATE on the parent.  O.o  The BEFORE INSERT Trigger on child does everything ... :)  My bad, read the OP request too literally, and created both triggers. Fails. Without the BEFORE UPDATE trigger = works perfectly.  :)

Comment: hmm, another odd feature of this site: I can't undo my downvote unless you edit your answer? O.o  odd.  Make a minor edit, and I'll change my downvote  ;)